# Is there any smart enough tool to build UML class-diagram based on not very complicated Java sources?

Tags: java, uml

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and I tried its tool for building class diagram. Unfortunatelly, it draws classes from java package as well as necessary classes. That's why built diagram is very messed.

Are there any more smart tool? Or, is there any way to 'turn off' drawing java classes in IDEA?

Answer (score 1):

Almost any reasonable UML tool provides this service. Sometimes you need to have a licensed version for this feature to be enabled.

I suggest that you simply check out the different tools.

Apparently [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/features.html#reveng) (open source) does reverse engineering but sadly, I've not had incredible success using that tool.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very good plugin for Eclipse that I use. It's called ObjectAid.
Just add this URL: http://www.objectaid.com to your Available Software page in Help -> Software updates and install the plugin.

It's a very simple drag and drop utility, that enables you the automatically add childern/parents to your class diagram.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try Gentleware's [Poseidon](http://www.gentleware.com/).

There is a free Community Edition.

Comment: Free is relative; last I checked, the community edition doesn't allow you to save a file unless you "rent" the product for ~$5.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend JUDE community edition.  It's an excellent UML tool that supports Java reverse engineering nicely.